# Docker Containers Java Spring MVC and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, containers, boot2docker, dockerfile

I have created two docker containers, one running MongodDb and one running Java Spring MVC on Tomcat 8. I have successfully linked the containers, but what I cannot understand is how you configure the java web app in one container to talk to mongodb in the other app.

Where do the connection string settings have to be setup in the java web app?

my Java Spring MVC app has the following `applicationContext.xml` settings

```
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="segmentation" />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
       <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.qantas.repository" />
```

when i run env in my web container I get

```
CON1MDB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.10

CON1MDB_PORT_27017_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.10:27017
```

my DB container is running and has data that I can access from within the terminal and my web app is up and running. I just can't connect to the db from the web app.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: applicationContext.xml settings are <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
        <mongo:db-factory dbname="segmentation" />
 
 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
 </bean>
      
        <mongo:repositories base-package="com.qantas.repository" />

Answer (score 2):

In your **applicationContext.xml** file you need to set the host to **host=con1mdb** (the alias you provided when you used the --link flag).The database container has a different IP from the server container so you can't use localhost or 127.0.0.1.

If you run:

```
docker run -d --name mongodb mongo
docker run -d --name tomcatserver --link mongodb:database tomcat
```

and inspect the **/etc/hosts** in the tomcat container you will see something like:

```
172.17.0.2  database 0e504e1d7f79 mongodb
```

In the above scenario you should set **host=database**